# Kendo UI Angular Chart multi axis support

Tags: kendo-ui

Does Kendo UI Angular Chart component support multi-axis?

Kendo UI https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/multiple-axes supports them but I can't find any example of documentation on how to do the same with the Angular components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular Kendo UI does support multi-axis, but out of the box they are only used by specific chart types. You will have to do custom JS work to modify which charts can use multi-axis.

This is the documentation for Axes included in Kendo UI for Angular: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/chart/elements/axes/#toc-multiple-scatter-chart-axes

Live Code Examples

**Multiple Categorical Axes**
https://mqkzpi.run.stackblitz.io/

**Multiple Scatter Chart Axes**
https://4hgbdr.run.stackblitz.io/

Comment: Greetings Brandon. Thanks for contributing. Check links to code examples you provid, they are broken. Also it's good idea to post valuable code inside the answer in case that external site goes down. Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Provided links are loading indefinitely.